# Entity not recognized

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I trained my luis model to recognize an intent called "requestDefintion" with example utterances such as: "What does BLANK mean" or "Can you explain BLANK to me?". 
It recognizes the intent correctly. I also added an entity called "topic" and trained it to recognize what topic the user is asking about. 
The problem is that luis only recognizes the exact topic the user is asking about if I used that specific term in one of the utterances before.

Does this mean I have to train it with all the possible terms a user can ask about or is there some way to have it recognize it anyway?

For example when I ask "What does blockchain mean" it correctly identifies the entity (topic) as blockchain because the word blockchain is in the utterance. But if I ask the same version of the question about another topic such as "what does mining mean", it doesn't recognize that as the entity.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean I have to train it with all the possible terms a user can ask about or is there some way to have it recognize it anyway?

You can try to use [phrase list features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-feature), which can help LUIS recognize intents and entities. For example, you can create a phrase list named " topic" that contains the values `BLANK`, `blockchain` and `mining` etc.

[image]

My test with utterance `what does mining mean`:

Using phrase list, the score is **0.94**

[image]

Not using phrase list, the score is **0.77**

[image]

**Note**: *If define too many intents, it becomes harder for LUIS to classify utterances correctly, please do not define too many intents.*

Comment: Thanks! That would still make it neccessary to add EVERY topic the user can come up with. Isn't there a way to make LUIS identify the topic/entity according to the context?